# Почему $mysql->query($query) иногда возвращает массив, а иногда объект

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Почему результат запроса

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = $mysql->query($query);
```

иногда возвращает массив, а иногда объект?

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 15 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 239 [type] => 0 )
```

Comment: а что в документации написано?

Comment: Там написано что возвращается либо объект `mysqli_result` либо `boolean`. И посему вопрос - откуда автор вопроса взял массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `mysqli_result` - это объект с мета-даными и контентом, которые были найдены в при вашем запросе. Чтобы полчить сами записи вы должны обратиться к методу `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` и передать туда ваш полученный объект `$result`.